# Finding general expression for line segment between two eccentered circles

Tags: geometry

It's been years since I've had any real amount of geometry, and I'm trying to tackle what I feel like is a fairly simple problem, but it's giving me aches.

Circle $X$ is fixed with centroid $A$ and has radius $R_1$. Circle $Y$ rotates about its centroid $B$ and has radius $R_2$. Circle $Y$ is contained within Circle $X$. $C$ is a point on circle $Y$. $D$ is the intersection of Circle $X$ and the normal drawn from Circle $Y$ at point $C$.

Shown in this schematic, the new translated locations $C'$ and $D'$ if Circle $Y$ is allowed to rotate alpha.

[Schematic of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEqiD.png)

I'm trying to determine two things:

1. What is the general expression for segment CD allowing for rotation alpha?
2. Given a rotation alpha, what is the **average** segment length CD on a hemispherical basis (i.e. average from $\alpha-90$ to $\alpha+90$) ?

---

How I'm thinking I might approach (brute-force) this problem:

Consider known coordinates for $A$ (origin) & $B$ (zero, AB). $C$ = (zero, AB+R2).

I can calculate the location of Point $C' $via:

$$C'_x = \cos(\alpha)\cdot (C_x-B_x) - \sin(\alpha)\cdot (Cy-B_y) + B_x = -\sin(\alpha)R_2$$
$$C'_y = \sin(\alpha)\cdot(C_x-B_x) + \cos(\alpha)\cdot (C_y-B_y) + B_y = \cos(\alpha)R_2 + AB$$

Knowing $B$ & $C'$, find intersection of line $BC'$ and circle $X$, which equals $D'$.
Use distance formula to determine line segment $C'D'$.

For the average .. integrate distance formula .. somehow. Is there a more elegant way to do this? Thank you kindly.

Comment: You could use the cosine rule in triangle ABD'.

Comment: It is an  elliptic integral of the second kind.